# Alternative to scrapy.contrib in scrapy spider code

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I found this example code in a textbook about web scraping. After running the spider it showing error and found out that scrapy.contrib is removed in 1.16 release of scrapy. How should i change this so it work. I am new to web scraping btw.

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class ArticleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'articles'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
                  'Benevolent_dictator_for_life']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='.*'), callback='parse_items',
                  follow=True)]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        url = response.url
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        text = response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()').extract()
        lastUpdated = response.css('li#footer-info-lastmod::text').extract_first()
        lastUpdated = lastUpdate.replace(
            'This page was last edited on ','')
        print('URL is: {}'.format(url))
        print('title is: {}'.format(title))
        print('text is: {}'.format(text))
        print('Last updated: {}'.format(lastUpdated))
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of scrapy you can simply import the modules as below

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
# add the rest of the code
```

Read more from the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html).